# jQuery $.get() with multiple attributes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've written the following code and can't figure out why it doesn't work.
In my php-error_log there is no error.

Im trying to change a row in a with ajax get. My variables are both defined and the Mysql-Connection works. So what am I doing wrong?

Javascript:

```
$.get("rename_task.php", {content: userinput, id: this_task});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$db_connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'helreak', 'Password', 'helreak_todo');
$task_content = $_GET['content']; 
$task_id = $_GET['id'];
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:"  . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($db_connect,"UPDATE list_1 SET Content=$task_content WHERE State=1 AND ID=$task_id");

mysqli_close($db_connect);
?>
```

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: is there an error message?  What doesn't work?

Comment: does it update in the database ?

Comment: What is the output of the AJAX call (use Firebug or equivalent to trace it)? That should give you a good pointer.

Comment: @ale No there is no error message.

Comment: @TusharGupta No it doesn't.

Comment: @AdrianWragg How exactly can I do that?

Comment: @HELREAK do you get any mysql error ...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I expect that it updates the selected row. It's sort of a syncing with the database.

Comment: See my answer below check if it works.

Comment: @HELREAK It depends on which browser you're using, but generally you should be able to monitor HTTP traffic with either the browser's tools, or with simple external proxy/monitoring software (the name of the most common one currently escapes me, sorry!)

Comment: @AdrianWragg Thanks, this helped. I can see an error now. :)

Comment: What response does the PHP send? Where is your JavaScript success handler function that does anything with the results? Please show it to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 <?php
    $db_connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'helreak', 'Password', 'helreak_todo');
        $task_content = $_GET['content']; 
        $task_id = $_GET['id'];
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:"  . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

        $query = ($db_connect,"UPDATE list_1 SET Content='$task_content' WHERE State=1 AND ID='$task_id' ");


    mysqli_close($db_connect);?>
```

Comment: Still getting no result. :(

Comment: Are you trying to update the table and see the results? And also please check the form method is the `method='get'` ?

Comment: Ok so now I'm finaly getting back an error. But the error is : ` syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_error' ` :D

Comment: ` PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_error' (T_STRING) in /var... on line 9, referer: http://... `

Comment: did you checked the column names because there is difference in `Content` and `content` and `ID` and `Id` ? also what is line 9?

Comment: Sry.. `mysqli_query($db_connect,"UPDATE list_1 SET Content='$task_content' WHERE State=1 AND ID='$task_id' ") or die mysqli_error();`

Comment: Sh**! I'm sooo sorry! I've copied your code now and it seems, that I forgot to change something in my code before. I don't really know what.. But it works now and thank you so much for your Time. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are no errors because you did not use `or die mysqli_error()` which you should have.

Second, assuming `Content` is a string, it should be in quotes `Content='$task_content'`. The query (without quotes) would have thrown an error had you added the `or die..` line